# not able to create Event based Task Scheduler using c sharp

Tags: c#, taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I tried to create window Task using c sharp. I made the code but the code is not working, I am getting runtime expcetionn. It is a event based Task scheduler. 
    I am trying to schedule a Task which will invoke at the change of WIFI network in system.

I tried to check a lot of articles from Microsoft as well as outside also. I don want to use any third party libraries likes "Quartz" or so.

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
         //Create a new task definition and assign properties
         TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();

         td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Git Config Details";

         // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
         EventTrigger Etrigger = new EventTrigger("Mircosoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Opertaional", "NetworkProfile", 10002);

                Etrigger.Enabled = true;

                td.Triggers.Add(Etrigger);

                // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
                td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(@"C:\projects\Own\powershell\first.bat"));

                // Register the task in the root folder
                ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Duplicate", td, TaskCreation.CreateOrUpdate, "NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORKSERVICE", null,
                                            TaskLogonType.ServiceAccount);
            }
```

Comment: `but the code is not working, I am getting runtime expcetionn` and you managed to purposely hide the exception from everyone, is there a reason for that? If not, help us help you by showing what exception you get... That have important information that help everyone (including you) to solve the problem

Comment: Please show what the exception that you got.

Comment: hey guys, I apologize for late reply here is the exception which I am getting on this.
(10,287):Subscription:<QueryList><Query Id="0" Path="Mircosoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Opertaional"><Select Path="Mircosoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Opertaional">*[System[Provider[@Name='NetworkProfile'] and EventID=10002]]</Select></Query></QueryList>

Answer (score 0):

my bad some spelling msitakes caused the issue. Microsoft and operational spelled wrong in my above code.

here is the new code for that which is in working condition now.

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
            {
                //Create a new task definition and assign properties
                TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
                td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Duplicate";

                // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
                EventTrigger Etrigger = new EventTrigger("Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational", "Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile", 10002);

                Etrigger.Enabled = true;

                td.Triggers.Add(Etrigger);

                // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
                td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(@"C:\projects\Own\powershell\first.bat"));

                // Register the task in the root folder
                ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Duplicate", td, TaskCreation.CreateOrUpdate, "NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORKSERVICE", null,
                                            TaskLogonType.ServiceAccount);
            }
```

Thanks to all folks commented on my post.